# Is there a way to create a new list item with other user using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client namespace

Tags: development, client-object-model, visual-studio, user-accounts

We have a SharePoint list in which each user has permission to view only records created by him.

I have a task to write a service that generates list items,
list item must be created by another user than the authenticated user of the server (for the reason mentioned in the beginning) in order to view the item by the user who "created" the item.

**problem:** we tried a lot and we cant change the creator of the list item to another user than the server user that is authenticated (no exception is thrown and the item is created successfully). how can we achieve that?

**constrains:**

- the service will run on a server that SharePoint server **not** installed on.
- we are using `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` namespace but we also can use SharePoint SOAP service if needed.

that is a draft of the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Security;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles;
using System.Net;

namespace SharePointClientSaveWithItherUser
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UpdateListItem();
        }

        public static void UpdateListItem()
        {
            var siteURL = "http://oportalXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
            var listName = "XXXXX";
            var createdBy = "XXXXXX";
            var modifiedBy = "XXXXXX";

            ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteURL);

            var login = "XXXXXX";
            var password = "XXXXXX!";

            var securePassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in password)
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            }


       //     SharePointOnlineCredentials credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);
            context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(login, securePassword, "XXXX"); ;

            List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
            FieldUserValue author = GetUsers(context, createdBy);
            FieldUserValue editor = GetUsers(context, modifiedBy);
            ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
            ListItem oListItem = list.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
            oListItem["Title"] = "TEST";
            oListItem["Author"] = author; // its not working the creator of the record is the authanticated user and not the author 
           // oListItem["Editor"] = editor;

            oListItem.Update();
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }

        //get user by username
        public static FieldUserValue GetUsers(ClientContext clientContext, string UserName)
        {

            FieldUserValue _userValue = new FieldUserValue();

            User _newUser = clientContext.Web.EnsureUser(UserName);

            clientContext.Load(_newUser);

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            _userValue.LookupId = _newUser.Id;

            return _userValue;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into using a service principal? You can create a new one using the appregnew.aspx page. You can then create a ClientContext using the client ID and client secret using the OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager.GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the `EnsureUser` method and pass the user's email address (`user.name@domain.com`) or domain name (`i:0#.w|domain\username`) to it to resolve the user and then assign it to the author field as below:

```
//use email address of user or login name
var emailAddress = "user.name@tenantname.com"  //or  i:0#.w|domain\username;

var user = context.Web.EnsureUser(emailAddress);
context.Load(user);
context.ExecuteQuery();

ListItem oListItem = list.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
oListItem["Title"] = "TEST";
oListItem["Author"] = user;                    

oListItem.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: its works great but this method will run as a wcf service from out app server so we need to use `context.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxx", "xxxx!", "xxx");`  in order to authenticate, this line of code is "overriding" the username of `EnsureUser()` method and the Author is returning to be the server user...is there a way you know from your experience to overcome this problem?  
`

Comment: BTW if i use `context.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;` on my pc it works and i can create new item behalf of other user...i wonder whats the reason...

Comment: @jonathana - unfortunately havent come across such as scenario :(

Comment: now its working perfect!!! when i tested the service on my pc i had this problem but when i uploaded the service to the server the problem was gone and its working as expected (i wonder why..). thank you very much again!!!